# ie11 pressing [Enter] in input text field results in text wrapping

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

This must be one of the weirdest bugs I've ever encountered in my Web development life.

What you see below is a screenshot of a styled but simple text input field (**NOT** a textarea) in IE11, using Angular and PrimeNG directives (although I don't think it has anything to do with these), after the user had typed something and pressed enter **in the middle** of the string (which triggers a search action):

[image: Screenshot of input text field with text wrapped in IE11]

As you may have noticed, half of the string is displayed in another line, as if the text field is actually a text area.

IE developer tools shows the HTML like this:

[image: HTML snippet for input text field with wrapped text in IE11]

The computed styles for this input field are the following:

[image: Computed styles for input text field with wrapped text in IE11]

I don't see any styles modifying the default behavior above.

So how on earth is it possible for a simple input text field to wrap the text under???

Comment: It is so strange. As you've described, the rendering input field and the styles seem not to affect the result. I'd like to ask that if your page has included some plugin that may affect the input field behaviour like this.Or could you share your original code of the input field so that it could be hlepful to reprodue the issue.

Comment: @JeniferJiang there are no installed plugins/addons that could interfere with this. The code is pretty straightforward from the rendered HTML snippet.

Comment: Could you share your related source code like a sample code in fiddle? This will be easier to test and find the issue.